# Error While Comparing Dates

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have an `NVARCHAR` column named `Receivingdate`. I want to compare its content with the current time, but when I call `WHERE (Receivingdate < Getdate())`, I get the following error:

> The conversion of nvarchar to datetime resulted in an out of range value

I insert the data using the following call from C#:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(ces).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what datatype is column 'Receivingdate '? It should be datetime2 (or datetime) NOT string....

Comment: it is nvarchar datatype

Comment: Simply put: Use the appropriate datetime datatype NOT varchar/nvarchar.

Comment: it gives same problem if i change datatype to datetime or datetime2

Comment: if i insert complete datetime like as 3/12/2013 12:00:00 AM then my query work i insert only date that give problem.....

Comment: Don't insert a string. Insert a DateTime. Also, Tip for future: Use ISO 8601 format dates like yyyy/mm/dd if outputting to string

Comment: You'll have to alter your table to first rename your actual ReceivingDate column in order to be able to add another of the correct data type (datetime) which you'll name ReceivingDate, then convert your strings in the renamed column into this column and update the rows, then drop this nvarchar column.

Comment: WHY DOES EVERYONE KEEP USING NVARCHAR FOR DATES? I don't understand string in the first place, but I *really* don't understand UNICODE strings!!!

Comment: @AaronBertrand what if i want to inject the [look of disapproval](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/%E0%B2%A0_%E0%B2%A0-look-of-disapproval) into my dates as a dummy record?

Comment: @swasheck brilliant sir.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing wrong is storing dates in an `NVARCHAR` column. Please stop doing that. Fix your table and make that column using the `DATE` data type. The error is caused by garbage data getting into your table. Find those rows using:

```sql
SELECT Receivingdate FROM dbo.YourTable 
  WHERE ISDATE(ReceivingDate) = 0;
```

Now, you'll need to either correct or get rid of those before you fix the data type. Then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
  ALTER COLUMN ReceivingDate DATE;
```

Next, stop converting to a regional string format when inserting. Just insert the `DateTime` value from C# without calling `.ToString()` at all. There is absolutely no reason you should ever be converting to date to string and back again through any of this process, except at the point where you want to display it.

Comment: ok but i want to show date in sql column in that format "dd/MM/yyyy" and also used that query on it

Comment: @SaimaMaheen, You can still query your data in a `DateTime` format. And any particular reason you must format as "dd/MM/yyyy" the column in an SQL select, rather than in c#?

Comment: @Saima why do you care about the format it's STORED in? Let SQL Server worry about that. Store it as a DATE and worry about formatting when you DISPLAY the value.

Comment: ok i insert date as sql date but now i want to show all dates of that column in report in "dd/MM/yyyy" format  how can i do that

Comment: CONVERT(CHAR(10), column, 103)

Comment: yes that i find thanxxxxxxxx i am new and not practice to ask question

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are trying to compare a string to a date.  Dates are numbers.  The only time to worry about format is when you are displaying them.

For what you have shown so far, change your c# code from

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(ces).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

to

```
 DateTime.Today;
```

and you should be ok.

Comment: This could work. Aside, it is bad practice to put dates into nvarchar. Unexpected problems such as this may occur. It allows for bad code to be written.

Comment: This will still be inserting strings into an inappropriate column type, only now it will be a mix of `09/03/2013` and `Mar  9 2013`. The error in the question is actually caused by other garbage that has already made it into the column, and we're not really fixing much by simply changing all future inserts while (a) leaving garbage data in the table and (b) leaving the column as a string.